# Laptop stuck in boot loop and cannot boot from any device

Tags: boot

My laptop is a Samsung NP900X3A.

I had installed Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop but was having trouble (I could only boot into windows). I then used a Linux live cd with efibootmgr to modify the list of boot options, adding only the Ubuntu and Windows ones. This was only after using boot-repair didn't fix anything.

Now I am stuck in an infinite boot loop with only those two options left in the boot list which don't work. I cannot boot from any other forms of media like my Linux live key either to fix it. I removed the main and cmos battery in an attempt to reset the bios, which it did, but didn't fix the disappearance of boot devices.

I'm out of ideas at this point. Does anyone know how to rescue my laptop?

Comment: Did you change the boot priorities in your bios? When you select to use your USB port before the HDD, you should be able to boot from that stick.

Comment: @Andre I don't have anything else in my boot priorities list other than the two entries leftover from my tinkering (ubuntu and windows). I can't boot into the OS, and I can't boot from a flash drive, so I don't know what to do now. Will wiping the laptop drive (plugged into my desktop) fix the problem?

Comment: No. you need to get into your bios. I don't know how the samsung bios looks like, but somewhere you should find the boot priorities. You have to change these in order to boot from your USB flashdrive. Well your flashdrive should be bootable obviously. I'll write you a suggestion how to proceed as an answer.

Comment: @Andre yes, I am inside the bios. The other devices like USB or network are just not there. That's why I'm having so much trouble trying to rescue myself! http://i.imgur.com/qwM6PFt.jpg

Comment: Ok thats really weired... I think you should unplug your hard drive and see what you can find on your boot priorities then. If all usual entries reappear, I would try to wipe that drive on your desktop (as you previously have asked for). Sorry I've never seen such a behaviour -.-

Comment: @Andre nope, all the usual entries don't appear even after removing the ssd.

Comment: Sorry I've been in Austria the past week. When they don't appear I guess that something is wrong with your mainboard. You could try to update your bios, but tbh: I've never had such a case and don't know how to fix that.